# Guide from TornadoFX: how to implement Customer class

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I am following TornadoFX Guide from here, trying to run the sample wizard:
[Wizard](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part2/Wizard.html)

and have implemented additional class Customer as follows, which is not running:

```
package com.example.demo.app

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.Period
import tornadofx.*

class Customer(name: String, zip: Int, city: String, type: String) {
    val zipProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(zip)
    var zip by zipProperty

    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(name)
    var name by nameProperty

    val cityProperty = SimpleStringProperty(city)
    var city by cityProperty

    val typeProperty = SimpleStringProperty(type)
    var type by typeProperty

}
```

How can I add `Customer.Type` as referenced here, these classes are taken from the Guide:

```
package com.example.demo.view

import com.example.demo.app.Customer
import com.example.demo.app.CustomerModel
import tornadofx.*
class CustomerWizard : Wizard() {
    val customer: CustomerModel by inject()

    override val canGoNext = currentPageComplete
    override val canFinish = allPagesComplete

    init {
        add(BasicData::class)
        add(AddressInput::class)
    }
}

class BasicData : View("Basic Data") {
    val customer: CustomerModel by inject()

    override val complete = customer.valid(customer.name)

    override val root = form {
        fieldset(title) {
            field("Type") {
                combobox(customer.type, Customer.Type.values().toList()) //Customer.Type, what is it?
            }
            field("Name") {
                textfield(customer.name).required()
            }
        }
    }
}

class AddressInput : View("Address") {
    val customer: CustomerModel by inject()

    override val complete = customer.valid(customer.zip, customer.city)

    override val root = form {
        fieldset(title) {
            field("Zip/City") {
                textfield(customer.zip) {
                    prefColumnCount = 5
                    required()
                }
                textfield(customer.city).required()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error is as follows, leaving me to wonder what Type is? Enum, Class, ...? `Error:(26, 50) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: Type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example above, `Type` is an enum, defined inside the `Customer` class, for example like this:

```
class Customer(name: String, zip: Int, city: String, type: Customer.Type) {
    enum class Type {
        Private, Company
    }

    val zipProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(zip)
    var zip by zipProperty

    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(name)
    var name by nameProperty

    val cityProperty = SimpleStringProperty(city)
    var city by cityProperty

    val typeProperty = SimpleObjectProperty<Type>(type)
    var type by typeProperty

}
```

Note that `typeProperty` was changed to `SimpleObjectProperty<Type>` as well.

Comment: ty @edvin syse. But why does the cancel button of the wizard not reject the latest changes? Is it a bug?

Comment: You might have a bug in your code, but you haven't posted the Wizard code so I can't know for sure. You must remember that input values edited will still be changed in the ViewModel, but will not be written back into the domain object until you do viewmodel.commit(). You can also do viewmodel.rollback() to explicitly roll back to the values from your domain object.

Comment: I answered it now :)